# Merging an existing list into the middle of a Python list literal

Tags: python, list, merge, literals, list-literal

When declaring a list literal in Python, is it possible to merge an existing list into the declaration? For example:

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
n = [10, 20, 30, l, 50, 60, 70]
```

This results in the following:

```
[10, 20, 30, [1, 2, 3], 50, 60, 70]
```

Note that the list l itself has been added as a single element, but what I really want is for l's elements to be added individually to the target list, like this:

```
[10, 20, 30, 1, 2, 3, 50, 60, 70]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Python 3.5 (See https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-350/, PEP448), This can be done using Python's unpack operator, which is an asterisk before the list:

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
n = [10, 20, 30, *l, 50, 60, 70]
```

The result is:

```
[10, 20, 30, 1, 2, 3, 50, 60, 70]
```

Comment: @GPhilo Thanks for the heads up. Do you know when this was introduced into python 3?

Comment: Found it - it was introduced in Python 3.5

Comment: AFAIR it was introduced in [PEP 448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) and Python 3.5

Comment: For python2.7 use this solution, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists

Answer (score 0):

This will works with `l` on any place

```
from itertools import chain   
for i in n:
   if isinstance(i, list):
      b+=list(chain(i))
   else:
      b+=[i]
```